# Last entry of Map not getting deleted?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

As a forward, I'm attempting to create an entity/component/system design for a game.  The first thing I'm trying is to handle entity creation and deletion.  I opted to try to use a native Map for this.

For some reason when I run this code, I see expected behavior until I reach the last element of the map where I see it's update being called several times over when the entry is seemingly not getting removed.

code:

---

```
class Vector{
   constructor(x, y){ this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}

class Enemy{
   constructor(id, x, y){
      this.id = id;
      this.pos = new Vector(x, y)
   }
   update(){
      this.pos.x++;
      console.log(Game.entities)
      if (this.pos.x > 10) Game.dispatch(this.id)
   }
}

const Game = {
    start: function(){
       this.entities = new Map;
       for (let i = 0; i<5; i++){
            const sid = Math.random();
            this.entities.set(sid, new Enemy(sid, i*20, 20))
       }
       this.tick(0)
    },
    dispatch: function(id){
        this.entities.delete(id)
    },
    tick: function(){
        for (let entity of this.entities.values()) {
            entity.update();
        }
        setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 100)
    }
}
Game.start()
```

Expected output:

---

```
test.js:12 Map(5) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.42078144104682513 => Enemy, 0.26799686976172143 => Enemy, 0.7289429408250698 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(5) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.42078144104682513 => Enemy, 0.26799686976172143 => Enemy, 0.7289429408250698 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(4) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.26799686976172143 => Enemy, 0.7289429408250698 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(3) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.7289429408250698 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(2) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
```

Actual output:

---

```
test.js:12 Map(5) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.42078144104682513 => Enemy, 0.26799686976172143 => Enemy, 0.7289429408250698 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(5) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.42078144104682513 => Enemy, 0.26799686976172143 => Enemy, 0.7289429408250698 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(4) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.26799686976172143 => Enemy, 0.7289429408250698 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(3) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.7289429408250698 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(2) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy, 0.31514175919106435 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
test.js:12 Map(1) {0.5025040680322241 => Enemy}
```

Answer (score 0):

didn't realize I was instatiating the objects at different positions.  oops! :(

it is working as intended if creating objects at same positions and updating accordingly.